# windows 2016, php dns query fails unless first run as admin

Tags: php, dns, windows-server-2016

Been trying to figure out an issue not being able to use php's dns_get_record when called in a webpage under IIS. Thru some trial an error i figured out it was a permission issue. I think I confirmed this when i temporarily added the app pool user the webpage was running under as part of the admin user group. Suddenly it started working. And surprisingly, it kept working even after i removed the app pool user from the admin group. I have 2 versions of php installed on the server. It was not working on either version. And now it works on both versions.

My guess at this point is that it wants to write to some temp/cache file and as a user it has permission to write to the file, but does not have permission to create the file. When i added it to the admin group it was able to create the file. This is purely a guess on my part.

Since i don't know the exact cause, i can't be sure it's really fixed. So would really appreciate if anyone might have a better idea of what's going on and how i can make sure it's fixed permanently.

Update1: some additional info - after removing admin rights on the app pool user, i can restart the app pool or even restart IIS through the IIS control panel and it keeps working. But, if i restart IIS using iisreset, it stops working until I give admin rights again and then run it once. I'm not sure what's different between restarting IIS in the IIS control panel, or using IISRESET, but something causes it to stop working again using iisreset.

Thanks

Comment: first of all when you restart iis from the control panel all it does is rereading the conf files and maybe re caching (depending on configuration) static/script files. when you reset you actually stopping and starting iis all the way. that is why your user was able to continue calling the aforementioned method even after the restart from the control panel

Comment: now for the permission question. could you provide us with the way you call the method and also the error that you get. I would also like to ask you to run the same method from the command line with php executable and tell me the output

Comment: stopping IIS from the control panel doesn't actually kill the process? And yes, i can run it from the command line without any problems. Although i was logged in as an admin when i ran it. And the error is dns query failed. The test code I am running is $dnsrecs = dns_get_record('google.com');

Comment: well running the command as admin is not giving much info, can you login as the aforementioned user and run first a ping command to the domain and post the results?
then as admin run `Get-DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy -Name 'BlockListPolicy' | Format-List *` and post the results as well?

Comment: Logging in as this user, who is just a member of the 'users' group, i was able to run the script from the command line without any problem. And I was unable to run the command you asked - it came back saying get-dnsserverqueryresolutionpolicy wasn't a recognized cmd or function. Did a quick google search for anyone else with that issue and someone suggested running import-dnsserver, but that failed as well saying no valid module file was found

Comment: no need to install anything, I thought because of the fact that you have a server os you would be managing dns from that server

Comment: nah, i stopped running my own dns a few years back, just seemed easier to let godaddy handle it since they let you run dns for domains even if they aren't registered/hosted with them.